# Advice required for job profile

Tags: work-environment, new-job

I joined a company 3 months back as a Business Analyst. Previously used to work as a Risk Analyst. During my job interview I was never asked a question about my studies as I had joined a Post Graduate course and completed that (was correspondence based and did while working as a Risk Analyst).

I was offered a position and good hike in salary, I accepted and joined. From Day 1, I was put on projects and I took it as a challenge. But after a month, the pressure and job expectations were too high. I couldn't cope and hence made mistakes, for which I was rebuked too. I took it upon myself that it was due my fault. This continued for the coming 2 months.

Yesterday, my manager told me that that I was being put on a PIP and I have a month to show results, I called my parents and told that I want to resign. My parents called my manager and asked the reason for non-performance as they were worried too. My manager told that I am hard working and sincere , but I not able to understand the requirements.

I called up my manager telling I want to put down my papers. He said that during my interview there was a expectation mismatch and he said that he will hand hold me for a month and teach me. Even after that I feel that this job is not my cup of tea then I can put down my papers and resign.

I want to know whether it is wise to give a month time and learn or resign and introspect / revise what was taught during my course for a month and half and then search for opportunities.

P.S. I was fresh out of my PG course and did not have prior experience in Business Analysis.The previous company is a huge company in Fortune 500 and the current company is startup types.

Comment: @Dan Wilson : No , its not normal . They asked for my managers number and I gave them.Even told them not to call , as I wanted to handle the whole situation myself.

Comment: Honestly, if you did not want them to call, you should not have given them the number.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere imo he should put his max effort into this 1month. Reason I think so is that manager offered to personally acclimatize the OP,which means he doesn't think this is a lost cause otherwise he wouldn't waste resources on this effort, and also even if it comes down to the OP getting fired he ll still have a valuable 1 month practical training done on top of everything he personally learned in his off-work time in regards to Business Analysis which is a subject he does seem like wanting to pursue further as a career path as mentioned.

Comment: ""revise what was taught during my course for a month and half""
From the wording of it, he does seem able to afford being unemployed for a short period of time, so even if he does get fired, being out of work wont be the deciding factor to take into account either.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere just from my pov, since he can afford short term unemployment, focusing that off-work time to delve deeper into B.A. on top of his training would be the most logical thing to do. Doubt he can balance a maximum effort workday with revising core BA off-work with searching for a new job/participating in related selection processes. So if he needs to choose 2 out of 3, the latter should be omitted for this month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My parents called my manager and asked the reason for non performance
>   as they were worried too.

First things first, this isn't school, if your parents call your work to ask about your performance you'll surely be making a bad impression on people that have expectations of you and assume you're an adult and can take on responsibilities on their behalf. Keep that in mind.

> He said that during my interview there was a expectation mismatch and
>   he said that he will hand hold me for a month and teach me .

Hiring people is expensive, letting people off is even more. You're given a second chance here, you re even offered to be hand-held through it. As far as I see it they make their maximum effort so you can assimilate and become a part of the team.

That said, DO NOT take it lightly, this second chance and the effort put in by your manager means all the more reasons for you to strive to do well. Do your best at work, use your off-work time to read relevant materials online, touch up what you learned in that course etc & so on. Since you do want to continue working in that sector, as made apparent in your last paragraph, take this chance and use it to its full extent, I don't see any merit whatsoever in quitting.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's an answer for this apart from "do what you feel is right".

It can be difficult going from one specialism to another, but it seems like they've done things the wrong way round here. They should have held your hand (as you put it) first, before threatening you with a performance improvement plan. They also should have expected the mismatch, given they knew your experience.

Personally, I'd take them up on the offer to learn more about Business Analysis. It sounds like you've got a good opportunity here and, if you do well, they'll look after you.

To draw from experience: I was offered a contract that was way too technical for me. About six weeks in, I was drowning... and everyone knew it. It got to the point where the CIO sat me down and had a frank discussion about my technical knowledge and experience. Similarly, he offered to show me what I didn't know and, what should have been a three-month contract, turned into a year.

If you ask for help, people are usually willing to help you.

**Edit:** It does seem a bit odd that your parents called your manager. Is that normal in India?

Comment: @Leon : The HR set that expectation , telling that a experienced person is joining . So naturally , the team had a expectation here even before I joined . There was also no training program to acquaint myself with the job I will be doing .

Comment: @SajalRoychowdhury not sure if you intended to reply to me or Dan but point made in my 2nd paragraph still stands as long as you do want to work as a business analyst(with the perks coming with it as you mentioned). The reasons that led you to be deemed as under-performing(as mentioned in your comment) are irrelevant to  assessing the situation from now on.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me :) Let me strive hard for the duration and see the outcome.